# Slide an appended <div> from right to left

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to slide a `<div>` from right to left that get's appended to it's parent. I'm not having much success with this.

What I'm trying to achieve is medium speed slide in from the right to left when it gets appended. I tried using jQueryUI as well as JQuery, but cannot get this right. What is the correct way to do this (without jQueryUI or if that cant be avoided, with it)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Side bar poll thingy</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.acceptUser, .rejectUser').click(function () {

        var action = $(this).attr('class');
            var type = $(this).data('id');


        var parentTag = $(this).parent("div");

        parentTag.empty();

        parentTag.append("<div class='flag' style='background:red;'>Success</div>").animate({left:'0px'});
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
UserName : Norman | SignedUp: 10-09-2013 | SignedUp Location: US

<div class="adminLinks">
    <span class="acceptUser" data-id="24">Accept</span>
    <span class="rejectUser" data-id="24">Reject</span>
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the newly appended element. So you can rewrite it to this:

```
 parentTag.append('<div class="flag" style="background:red;">Success</div>');
 parentTag.find('div.flag').animate({ left: '0px' });
```

Another way of doing it, is this, without the need of `.find()`:

```
$('<div class="flag" style="background: red;">Success</div>')
    .appendTo(parentTag)
    .animate({ left: '0px' });
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/syaDV/) (Version 1)

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/93pse/) (Version 2)

Comment: Works Nice. Is there a way I can get it to slide in from the beginning right side of the `div` it's in, rather that a particular position as you've done?

Comment: You can use `left: 100%` if the parent container has set position to relative or absolute, see [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PcGFB/).